# Invalid/Hidden Characters 0x1E and 0x1F

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0

Currently we have developed an application and on some cases users copy paste some translated text from third party tool and while translating the text would include 0x1E / 0x1F hidden character which user noticing but when we do export the data to XML format these characters are shown in the file.
So my question, is there a way to show these characters in Textarea control, so user can remove those characters before saving it
if that is not possible then what is the option to remove these Characters.
Web application is developed using ASP.NET C# and SQL Server as Back End.

Answer (score 3):

Those 1E and 1F are control codes, `record separator` and `unit separator` respectively (see [C0 and C1 control codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#Field_separators)). As far as I know these are control codes, not displayed by most controls, especially standard ones. TextArea hides them too, like bells, carriage returns, line feeds.

You can manually replace those values using `string.Replace`:

```
yourValue.Replace("\x1E", "").Replace("\x1F", "");
```